# ActiveMQ jolokia queue name with slashes

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jolokia

I'm trying to retrieve the queue size of a given queue using jolokia interface of ActiveMQ. My queue name is `/some/queue` and because of the slashes I can't get the API to work correctly.

Here's what I tried:

```
curl -XGET --user admin:admin "http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=/some/queue,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker/QueueSize" | python -m json.tool

curl -XGET --user admin:admin "http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=%2Fsome%2Fqueue,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker/QueueSize" | python -m json.tool
```

One with not encoded `/` and the other with encoded to `%2F`, both queries return `javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException`.
When I try to retrieve other queues it works. When I do `destinationName=*` it lists my queue:

```
    "org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=/some/queue,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker": {
        "QueueSize": 0
    },
```

How should I encode `/` in jolokia queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, to escape `/` in jolokia queue names one has to use `!` in front of slash (source https://jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html#escape-rules).

So the correct CURL for this is (in bash `!` has to be escaped with `\`):

```
curl -XGET --user admin:admin "http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=\!/some\!/queue,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker/QueueSize" | python -m json.tool
```